# How can I Import the Existing ElasticSearch Data into new ElasticSearch

Tags: windows, elasticsearch

I had installed ElasticSearch, now all I've is the data directory of previously installed ElasticSearch. Now I've re-installed the ElasticSearch into my machine.

How can I import that previous data into my current ElasticSearch?

Comment: Just copy the data folder from there to your machine

Comment: I already did that but didn't work out. In logs its giving error  

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a state file to recover from among [[id:1, legacy:false, file:D:\PUP_Application\Soft\elasticsearch-2.2.0\data\elasticsearch\nodes\0\_state\global-1.st], [id:76, legacy:true, file:D:\PUP_Application\Soft\elasticsearch-2.2.0\data\elasticsearch\nodes\0\_state\global-76]]`

Comment: what about the versions of both installations?

Comment: I found that it was version issue, now I installed 2.0.0 and replaced the data directory, but I'm not able to see my previous cluster or data